# Pigpio get_pwm_dutycycle returning old values

Tags: pigpio

Using pigpio, I can set the hardware PWM value but getting it seems to consistently give three of the old values, a zero and then the new value, as well as the old value returned with the initial command

```
>>> gpio.hardware_PWM(18, 10000, 10)
10000
>>> for i in range(7):
...     print(i, ' ', gpio.get_PWM_dutycycle(18))
... 
0   10000
1   10000
2   10000
3   0
4   10
5   10
6   10
>>> gpio.hardware_PWM(18, 10000, 100000)
10
>>> for i in range(7):
...     print(i, ' ', gpio.get_PWM_dutycycle(18))
... 
0   10
1   10
2   10
3   0
4   100000
5   100000
6   100000
>>> gpio.hardware_PWM(18, 10000, 1000)
100000
>>> for i in range(7):
...     print(i, ' ', gpio.get_PWM_dutycycle(18))
... 
0   100000
1   100000
2   100000
3   0
4   1000
5   1000
6   1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the cli session I was testing in had multiple instances or something similar. Reboot fixed to look like Joan's answer

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing.

These are my results.

```
>>> pi.hardware_PWM(18, 10000, 7733);pi.get_PWM_dutycycle(18)
0
7733
>>> pi.hardware_PWM(18, 10000, 72733);pi.get_PWM_dutycycle(18)
0
72733
>>> pi.hardware_PWM(18, 10000, 73);pi.get_PWM_dutycycle(18)
0
73
```

Comment: Thanks figured out it was my CLI session had backed up a few instances